# What are the points of differentiability of $f(z)=\vert z \vert^2+\iota \bar z +1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

**The function $f(z)=\vert z \vert^2+\iota \bar z +1$ is differentiable at**

> $1)\iota$
>
> $2)1$
>
> $3)-\iota$
>
> $4)$No point in $\mathbb C$

Solution:
$f(z)=\vert z \vert^2+\iota \bar z +1=z\bar z+\iota \bar z +1$

If $f$ is differentiable at $z_0\implies f$ satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations at $z_0\implies \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=0 $ at $z=z_0\implies z+\iota=0\implies z=-\iota$.So, $f$ is differentiable at $z=-\iota$ only.

Now,$lim_{z\rightarrow -\iota}\frac{f(z)-f(-\iota)}{z+\iota}=lim_{z\rightarrow -\iota} \frac{z\bar z+\iota \bar z +1-1}{z+\iota}=lim_{z\rightarrow -\iota}\frac{\bar z(z+\iota)}{z+\iota}=lim_{z\rightarrow -\iota} \bar z=\iota$,.

But in answer key it is given that $f$ is differentiable at no point in $\mathbb C$.
**Where i'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Depends on the definition of differentiability. To be differentiable at "one point" is not really interesting. In general one wants to be differentiable in an open neighboorhood of the point, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the standard notation is $i$, not $\iota$.

Other than that, you are right. The function is differentiable at $-i$ and only there. And $f'(-i)=i$.